# .view() throws an error "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "

Tags: python, view, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Here is the code I am working on and refering the following website
[Link](http://scikit-fuzzy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html)

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl


soc = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'soc')
log = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'log')
aut = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'aut')

log.automf(3)
soc.automf(3)
aut.automf(3)

soc.view()
```

I am running this code in Jupyter notebook

Comment: Try adding the `%matplotlib inline` magic at the beginning of the cell. It switches the matplotlib backend to one that displays inline in the notebook itself and is generally required for matplotlib to work in Jupyter, unless you are plotting to a file.

Comment: Thanks Hristo, It did show the output